# Show tab previews in the Windows taskbar stopped working

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Settings for show tab previews in the Windows taskbar:
[image: settings for show tab previews in the Windows taskbar]

Yesterday I found this fantastic option in Firefox 110.0.1 (64-bit), called "Show tab previews in the Windows taskbar".

Today, it suddenly stopped working. Tried to uncheck / check the Settings, restart the browser, even restarted the computer, but it just doesn't work anymore.

**Update**

- By not working I mean it behaves as if the check box is not checked
- Right after I had posted, it decided to work again. Without me changing anything. Then it stopped working for a while, then it's working again. Just now, it stopped working. Like a loose connection in electricity :)

**Update2**

- Just figured out what the "loose connection" is. It seems it can not handle more than 20 tabs! Which is precisely what I would need this function for...

Comment: It is working here. Try running DISM / SFC  ......   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? Do other applications show previews correctly?

Comment: On this Windows PC, with "Show tab..." enabled, the *title* of the current tab is shown, e.g., "Firefox - Sho" for this tab.  A long title, though, is truncated.